# AWS IP Addresses - Are they required if the EC2 instance is behind an ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS configuration comprising of 1 ELB (Load Balancer) and 2 EC2 instances (Web Servers). The 2 EC2 instances currently have an IP (EIP) associated with each. Do I actually need these IP address if the web servers are behind an ELB? How about for SSH connections (Putty etc) do I need the IP address for this? I am just interested as I can see benefits in dropping the IP addresses - would allow easier horizontal scaling etc.

Comment: I don't think this belongs on SO. This is more of a [Super User](http://superuser.com) question. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't need Elastic IP Addresses for your instances. I suggest you to configure [Auto Scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) for your application for durability, stability and faster response time.

The number of Instances will be dynamic, depending on CPU Utilization. This is how you do it: [Auto scaling your website with Amazon Web Services (AWS) – Part 2](http://www.cardinalpath.com/autoscaling-your-website-with-amazon-web-services-part-2/)

As for SSHing your instances, you have to figure out Public DNS of your Instances first, but it's easy to accomplish it with EC2 API Tools or AWS Console.